# Java GUI - storing input/calculations into txt tile

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jbutton, string-parsing

I've got a project where I need to get user input and then perform a volume calculation, all of which I have accomplished for a few different shapes.  However, I need to be able to store the input and calculation into a file for each shape into a file from which I can read later if selected.
I've tried to do this a few different ways, to no avail.  All of which have gave me a syntax error except for my latest try.  This try, however, doesn't seem to write to a file and only returns 0.0 on a single line.  Any help would be appreciated

```
public JButton getCalculateButton()
{
    JButton spa; 
    spa = new JButton("Calculate Volume");
    spa.setMnemonic('C');
    spa.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {               
            DecimalFormat num = new DecimalFormat(",###.##");
            double length, depth, volume;
            String instring;

            instring = lengthField.getText();
            if (instring.equals("")){
                instring = "0";
                lengthField.setText("0");
            }
            length = Double.parseDouble(instring);

            instring = depthField.getText();
            if (instring.equals("")){
                instring = "0";
                depthField.setText("0");
            }
            depth = Double.parseDouble(instring);

            volume = length * 8 * 4.8284 * depth;
            volumeField.setText(num.format(volume));

        }
    });
    return spa;
}

public JButton getSaveButton(){
    JButton save; 
    save = new JButton("Save Data");
    save.setMnemonic('C');
    save.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            PrintWriter writer;
            try {
                writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("spaFile.txt"));
                writer.printf(String.valueOf(length), String.valueOf(depth), String.valueOf(volume));
                writer.close();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }           
    });

    return save;
}
```

That is part of my GUI, that does the calculation and hopefully would have stored the data, but doesn't.

```
public JButton getSearchButton()
{
    JButton search; 
    search = new JButton("Search");
    search.setMnemonic('S');
    search.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {               
            FileInputStream fileStream;
            try {
                fileStream = new FileInputStream("spaFile.txt");
                 DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fileStream);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    System.out.println(reader.readLine());
                    reader.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    return search;
}
```

}

That is the part to read, though I don't have it fully as a GUI yet for testing purposes.

Comment: If you still haven't solved this problem, I suggest that you step back and write *another* small program which illustrates the issues that you encounter. This is called an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Doing this will help you understand the problem more clearly and maybe even find a solution on your own. If you still have problems, going through this process makes your question more clear in your own mind so that you can write out your question here in a precise way and get the help you want more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you really want

```
writer.printf(String.valueOf(length), String.valueOf(depth),
    String.valueOf(volume));
```

in the ActionListener of the save button. That statement uses `String.valueOf(length)` as the string that will be formatted and everything after it as formatting specifications; you probably want

```
writer.printf(String.valueOf(length) + ", " + String.valueOf(depth) +
    ", " + String.valueOf(volume));
```

---

Also: if you access `length`, `depth` and `volume`, make sure you're in a scope that can actually see those variables. If your values show up as 0.0 for all of those, that means you didn't assign the values you want them to have in the place where you read in those values.

---

Here's some code I recently used to save some information in a .txt file:

```
try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path);

        for (Movie movie : movies) {
            writer.write(movie.toString() + LINE_SEPARATOR);
        }

        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The variables' names hopefully are telling you what their purpose is. Note: this will overwrite the content of the file every time you use the code; to append stuff to the file, use `Writer#append(..)`; see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) on that (note that you probably want some specific `Writer`subclass, not the generic one).

Comment: That did help the problem of only showing a single 0.0, now it shows the 3 entries I used however it still isn't saving the data and only showing 0.0's (3x).  It also still isn't creating a physical txt file either, seems to be only a temporary read file as I can't find the txt in elcipse nor does it append if I re-open the program, just starts over.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the documentation on [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). I'll append some code to my answer regarding how I recently (and probably amateurishly) printed stuff I needed persisting to a .txt file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is here

```
writer.printf(String.valueOf(length), String.valueOf(depth), String.valueOf(volume));
```

`printf` is print format. You can read about that [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html). You would want to use either `print` or `println` depending on how you want your data to be saved. To save the three values on separate lines, you could use

```
writer.println(String.valueOf(length));
writer.println(String.valueOf(depth));
writer.println(String.valueOf(volume));
```

or if you wanted them to be on the same line separated by commas you could use

```
writer.print(String.valueOf(length) + "," + String.valueOf(depth) + "," + String.valueOf(volume));
```

Comment: Thank you sir, however it seems that my file isn't creating all together.  I know have the proper formatting but no saved data.